# Design Django's models using ManyToManyField for multivendor scheme?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model of **Item** with their respect **Owner**, each item can have multiple owners and each owner can have multiple items. Like below:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(DjangoUser)

class Item(models.Model):
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='**ItemOwner**')

class ItemOwner(models.Model): 
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta(models.Model.Meta):
        db_table = 'items_owners'
```

I also have a class **Price** and **PremiumPrice** to set price for item:

```
class **Price**(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12) 

class **PremiumPrice**(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price)
```

As you can see, each item can have only 1 price set by the class **PremiumPrice**, each item was owned by owners of that item, any owners can change price but the price is unique for that item. Also, when someone purchase that item, it was processed by the class **PurchaseItem** like below:

```
class PurchaseItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'purchase_item'
        unique_together = ('item', 'user')
```

Now, I want to convert it to multivendor scheme. Each item can be owned by multiple owners and each owner can set their own price for the items their own. 
So what I think i need to do is to add price to Item model and create a new class **ItemPrice** (to add price for each item):

```
class Item(models.Model):
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ItemOwner')
    prices = models.ManyToManyField(Price, through='ItemPrice')

class ItemPrice(models.Model): 
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price)
    class Meta(models.Model.Meta):
        db_table = 'items_prices'
```

Adn then change the class **PremiumPrice**: item from OneToOneField to **ForeignKey**, also include owner:

```
    class PremiumPrice(models.Model):
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
        price = models.ForeignKey(Price)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

To record each transaction, class PurchaseItem also need to include the owner and **unique_together** also need new value:

```
class PurchaseItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'purchase_item'
        unique_together = ('item', 'user', 'owner') #
```

But I still feel unsure if i'm correct or not. So if you have any comments/suggestions about errors/pitfalls i might have, please let me know. I'm really appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your models seem a little more complicated than they need to be. You're using `through=` all over the place, but it's not actually required unless you're [adding extra fields to a many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany).

Assuming your requirements are as described rather than as coded, you can boil this down to:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(DjangoUser)
    owned_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='ItemSale')
    purchased_items = models.ManyToManyfield(Item, related_name='purchasers')

class Item(models.Model):
    pass

class ItemSale(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owners')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12)
```

You can still access an item's `owners` and `prices` (the latter by looking at related `ItemSale` objects).

Comment: Thank you supervacuo. In fact here is what I extract from a very structured and big project that has been optimized, classes like Item & User have nearly 60 fields with a lot of things tight together. So i think that i can't only add 2 fields owned_items and purchased_items to the code and it will work, since it will break the structures in general. My code above is not so complicated i think, what i have done is to show my process of thinking and what i have changed, so it is a little long to read.

Comment: Ah, I was wondering if you had extracted it from a larger project. I think my point still stands, though — you don't need `PurchaseItem`, `PremiumPrice`, `ItemPrice` *etc.* unless you're actually storing information (beyond the `ForeignKey`s to related objects) on them.

Comment: I realise it's probably not what you want to hear, but I'm proposing you change your data representation to be less complicated (my 12 lines of code do the same as your ~3 dozen, and with 3 fewer database tables).

Comment: If you do this, adding per-owner prices for your `Item` objects is the first time you'd need an intermediary model. If not, my answer probably won't help you, sorry.